# If I store music in CloudDrive, can I play it in somehow?

Tags: icloud, music

I do not realy like this iTunes syncronization, connect device with cabel, start iTunes, .. too complicate. Can I sync and play music via CloudDrive?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unless you use a specific third-party app that allows this (I don't know of any) then synchronisation of music from a computer to an iOS device with iCloud Drive is not possible.

However, you may find that [iTunes Wi-Fi syncing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6474) sufficiently solves the problem you describe of having to physically connect your iOS device to your computer in order to synchronise media.

Comment: Do you know wether I can access iTunes music library from iOS App? Because iCloud Drive I can access.